# Odoo - How can i send a custom message to followers

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12, sendmessage

I want to send a cuustom message to followers when record is created
My class :

> ```
> class StockAlert(models.Model):
>     _name = "stock.alert"
>     _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']
>
>     responsable_id = fields.Many2one('res.users' ,store=True)
>
>     @api.multi
>     def write(self, vals):
>       result = super(StockAlert, self).write(vals)
>       for record in self:
>           followers= []
>           if record.responsable_id.partner_id.id not in record.message_follower_ids.ids:
>               followers.append(record.responsable_id.partner_id.id)
>           record.message_subscribe(followers)
>       return result
>
>     @api.model
>     def create(self, vals):
>       result = super(StockAlert, self).create(vals)
>       for record in result:
>           followers= []
>           if record.responsable_id.partner_id.id not in record.message_follower_ids.ids:
>               followers.append(record.responsable_id.partner_id.id)
>           record.message_subscribe(followers)
>       return result
> ```

Called the chatter on my view :

```
<div class="oe_chatter">
            <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
             <field name="activity_ids" widget="mail_activity"/>
            <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>          
          </div>
```

Any help please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully sure the follower subscription is correct this way, but posting a message should be very easy. Right after the subscription do:

```py
record.message_post(body)  # body should be a string
```

Look right into the defintion of `message_post` to get more possible parameters like `subject` or `partner_ids`.

`partner_ids` could be interesting for you, because this parameter can be used to autosubscribe on `message_post`. For example in `create`:

```py
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    result = super().create(vals)
    for record in result:
        partner_ids = record.responsable_id.partner_id.ids
        body = 'hello world'
        record.with_context(mail_post_autofollow=1).message_post(
            body, partner_ids=partner_ids)
    return result
```